# MFMailComposeViewController with 2 separate texts

Tags: ios, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to make message like hamburger:

text

image

text

Problem is that I have only last text. Is there way to insert text not one times in email?

```
    [mailController setMessageBody:@"text 1" isHTML:NO];
    [mailController setMessageBody:@"text 2" isHTML:NO];
```

Comment: what about `[mailController setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", text1, text2] isHTML:NO];`

Comment: You can't really have a message body with an embedded image. There are solutions that works in some cases, but many email clients won't show the embedded image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `setMessageBody:isHTML:` it overrides any previous content with whatever is passed into that method so if you want to build up the content your best bet is to append the content and once it is ready call `setMessageBody`